# Why Java Builder pattern over Java Bean pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

It has been suggested in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch that if we are facing a scenario in which we have a lot of fields in our bean we should consider using Builder patter over telescopic or java bean pattern. After reading an explanatory excerpt from the book I stumbled upon the term invariant. I thought a lot of cases of invariants but couldn't really think of a case that we cannot enforce the user to use the necessary fields involved in invariance by providing them constructor of such signature only. But is it good to be doing such things? What invariance can we use in a builder pattern to ensure we are using the pattern when we are required and not just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> couldn't really think of a case that we cannot enforce the user to use the necessary fields involved in invariance by providing them constructor of such signature only

That is true. However, it may be fine if you have 3, maybe 4 arguments. Starting with 5, your constructor will start to be very long.

> What invariance can we use in a builder pattern to ensure we are using the pattern when we are required and not just for the sake of it.

The builder in itself has no invariants; it is mutable, non thread safe. It can however generate classes with lots of invariants. Immutable classes, even; and these have a lot of advantages (they are, for instance, inherently thread safe).

Another big advantage of using a builder is that you can check the correctness of the arguments in the builder itself, and avoid all these checks in the constructor.

Not to mention that if you have several constructors you'll very probably have to duplicate the checks. With a builder you'll only have to make those checks once -- in the corresponding `.with*()` method.

Comment: fge ==> I agree for the most parts of it the generation of immutable classes and thread safe classes using Builder pattern but even as much naive it might seem I am still a bit confused with the term invariant what is invariant in a bean exactly ? Is it the dependence of one field on another field so if we initialize the dependent field before an dependency then it will cause an illegal state?

Comment: An invariant of an instance is a field which will never change during that instance's lifetime. In a bean, there are in fact no invariants at all... At least in "pure" beans.

Comment: As to field dependencies, if you use a builder, you can check such dependencies when you .build()

Comment: Okay... thanks a lot... its simple invariant (that does not vary). Thanks for a beautiful explanation.

Comment: I even got further than that in several of my projects with what I call "freeze/thaw" --> I can generate builders from immutable instances and back, and those are two very, very simple interfaces

Comment: `and avoid all these checks in the constructor` - I'm a little bit conservative about that, what about if I create an instance of the class using reflection ?

Comment: But its really rare to manually freeze the object before the complete instantiation and not letting the user use it. Can you share the interface of your freeze/thaw?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev uhmmm, don't do that? ;) Note that even with deserialization libraries (Jackson does that) you can use builders if you want.

Comment: @Sourabh https://github.com/fge/btf

Comment: Thanks I will definitely explore it. :)

Comment: @SvetlinZarev more generally though, I nearly never use reflection, nor beans, and when I deserialize, I deserialize classes simple enough that I don't need constructor argument checks; ultimately, though, that is a question of tastes

Comment: @fge I agree with you, and still it gives me the creeps :), BTW As far as I remember it was written in the book that validation *should* be done in the constructor too, besides in the builder, or am I mistaken ?